# Remove nomodeset from grub not working

Tags: 18.04, nomodeset

I currently have nomodeset enabled every time I boot up (I added it using sudo /etc/default/grub and then sudo update-grub) in order to fix a blackscreen issue regarding my nvidia gfx card.

Now,I have problems with suspend mode not working and brightness controller not functioning which is expected. Using e in the grub bootloader and changing nomodeset to nouveau.modeset=0 fixed all of these problems (no blackscreen too), but now I have a new one: I can't seem to remove nomodeset permanently from grub. I was able to add nouveau.modeset=0 successfully, but nomodeset still stays as a boog flag even after using sudo grub-update. What's even more weird is if I view /etc/default/grub in nano, nomodeset isn't shown here, yet it's flag is still present in the grub bootloader when pressing e.
Is there any way to completely remove nomodeset from my boot flags? 
[image: nano shown here]

Comment: You remove it the same way you added it.Edit `sudo nano /etc/default/grub`  and then `sudo update-grub`. With nVidia  you should only need nomodeset until you install correct nVidia driver from Ubuntu repository. https://askubuntu.com/questions/61396/how-do-i-install-the-nvidia-drivers

Comment: Like I said, and as you can see in the picture above, nomodeset doesn't show up there so I can't remove it ... I'm looking for a different way. I thought about removing all nomodeset manually from /boot/grub/grub.cfg since I can see nomodeset entries there, and then run update-grub. Is it safe?

Comment: The sudo update-grub command rewrites grub.cfg every time it is run based on what is in /etc/default/grub and the scripts in /etc/grub.d. You do not edit /boot/grub/grub.cfg.

Comment: I see. The problem is I can't see nomodeset flag in /etc/default/grub using nano in order to remove it...you can see that in the picture. Is there any other workaround to remove it? Thanks!

Comment: The command you neet to run is not `sudo grub-update` but `sudo update-grub`.

Comment: That was a mistake, I was using sudo update-grub..it did not remove nomodeset, but I was able to add nouveau.modeset=0 that way.